# How to get the 10.10 Ambiance theme on 10.04

Tags: upgrade, themes, ambiance

The new theme looks better and polished than the on on 10.04. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/install-updated-light-themes-version-in.html